# How can I run a flask app and celery worker with a single Heroku dyno

Tags: heroku, celery, gunicorn, worker, dyno

So my Procfile currenlty looks like:

```
web: gunicorn --preload --log-file - application:app
worker: celery -A celery worker --loglevel=INFO --beat
```

This costs 2 dynos and my worker has very low usage at the moment. Is there a way to run both gunicorn and the worker with a single dyno?